# Error 502 - Bad Gateway when trying to set up a server using Cloudflare and Nginx on port 8080

Tags: nginx, ssl, cloudflare, vps, self-hosting

I am setting a website using Nginx and Cloudflare. I followed the steps from a website, but for some reason, every time it keeps dropping the same 502 error. I already checked the hostname and it's the correct, plus Nginx appears to be 100% working. These are the steps that I followed(The guide was made in 2020 but for example, I also checked if things like the Cloudflare IPs where up to date):

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
sudo ufw status
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw reset
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow ftp
```

Up to date ips but still check on cloudflare linked pages, only allow https.

```
sudo ufw allow from 173.245.48.0/20 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 103.21.244.0/22 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 103.22.200.0/22 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 103.31.4.0/22 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 141.101.64.0/18 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 108.162.192.0/18 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 190.93.240.0/20 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 188.114.96.0/20 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 197.234.240.0/22 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 198.41.128.0/17 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 162.158.0.0/15 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 104.16.0.0/12 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 172.64.0.0/13 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 131.0.72.0/22 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 2400:cb00::/32 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 2606:4700::/32 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 2803:f800::/32 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 2405:b500::/32 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 2405:8100::/32 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 2a06:98c0::/29 to any port https
sudo ufw allow from 2c0f:f248::/32 to any port https

sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw status
```

ok now let's install nginx:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

some tuto to get commands and stuffs:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04
http://archive.vn/sjBvU

let's configure our server:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default (or with ftp)
```

put the ngninx config file instead, don't forget to change your hostname
ctrl+x
y

```
server {
if ($host = www.hostname.ltd) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
if ($host = hostname.ltd) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

listen 80;
server_name hostname.ltd www.hostname.ltd;
return 404;
}

server {
client_max_body_size 100M;

location /robots.txt {
    return 200 "User-agent: *
Disallow:";
}


location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
client_max_body_size 100M; # max file size for users to upload
}

}


sudo systemctl enable nginx
sudo systemctl start nginx
```

check for syntax errors:
s`udo nginx -t`

now let's get a ssl certificate with cerbot and cloudflare that auto renew
get the latest instructions in there
https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-nginx
go to "wildcard" and follow the steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
    
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
    
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install certbot python3-certbot-nginx
    
sudo apt-get install python3-certbot-dns-cloudflare
```

get your Global API key in there
https://dash.cloudflare.com/profile/api-tokens
copy the key somewhere and:

```
sudo mkdir /root/.secrets/
sudo nano /root/.secrets/cloudflare.ini
```

then put your token and past this (change mail and api key)

```
# Cloudflare API credentials used by Certbot
dns_cloudflare_email = myemail@email.com
dns_cloudflare_api_key = my-super-secret-api-key000000
```

Save

```
sudo chmod 0700 /root/.secrets/
sudo chmod 0400 /root/.secrets/cloudflare.ini
```

run this to generate the certificate (don't forget to change the hostname):

```
sudo certbot certonly \
  --dns-cloudflare \
  --dns-cloudflare-credentials /root/.secrets/cloudflare.ini \
  -d hostname.ltd \
  -d www.hostname.ltd
```

(Note: you are limited to 5 certificate a week per domain by cerbot)

set email address and agree to terms
It can take some times, be patient.

Set automatic renewal:

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

now change the nginx config file to use ssl on port 443:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/defaultor by ftp



server {
if ($host = www.hostname.ltd) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
if ($host = hostname.ltd) {
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

listen 80;
server_name hostname.ltd www.hostname.ltd;
return 404;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name hostname.ltd www.hostname.ltd;
client_max_body_size 100M;

location /robots.txt {
    return 200 "User-agent: *
Disallow:";
}


location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
client_max_body_size 100M; # max file size for users to upload
}

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hostname.ltd/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hostname.ltd/privkey.pem;
    
}
```

Check that everything works:

```
sudo systemctl restart 
nginx sudo nginx -t
```

Now run:

```
sudo systemctl start mywebsite1
```

And you should see MyWebsite1 running on your host name.
You can try to reboot to check that lynxchan start well on boot.

Is there something wrong with these test steps? And how can I fix this problem?